# Ajax call produces Internal Server Error 500

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have the following code in my ASP.NET web site that simply displays "Hello World" when a button is clicked:

**ASPX File:**

```
          $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (response)
                 {
                     alert(response.d);
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert(response.d);
                 }
            });
```

**.CS Code behind File:**

```
     /// <summary>
     /// Summary description for WebService1
     /// </summary>
     [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
     [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
     public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
     {

         [WebMethod]
         public string HelloWorld()
         {
             return "Hello World";
         }
     }
```

This works fine whenever it is ran locally on my PC (Launched from Visual Studio Debugger)  but when I deploy my website to a live server from my hosting company it does not work.

I use the Chrome Debugging Tools to view the the response in the ajax error function and it shows I get an "**Internal Server Error 500**"

I'm not sure what is going wrong because it works locally but not on a live server.  Is there any Web.Config settings that I have to use??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add to your web.config the following, under `<configuration>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <deployment retail="false" />
</system.web>
```

There is a runtime error that your code generates, and it doesn't seem to be coming from the code you posted. Adding the above snippet in the right place will help you trace the root cause.

Note that the `<deployment retail="false" />` might be unnecessary, it depends if the machine hosting your code has this value set to `true` in it's `machine.config`. If so, it will override other customErrors settings in your web.config. Though unlikely, I added it just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I see that I have these already turned on.  How can I see the output of any errors??

Comment: WHen I added the <deployment retail="false" /> I got the error when loading the page: "Server Error in '/' Application." Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineOnly' beyond machine.config."  And the other switches do not appear to highlight any errors either.

Comment: Ok, we tried :) then remove it and leave everything else. Do you get a more verbose error now?

Comment: When you say a more verbose error, do you mean in the 'response' that is returned by Ajax?? If so, the 'StatusText' it is still saying 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: Not sure what is 'StatusText' in this context, but I was referring to a page similar to this: http://i2.asp.net/asp.net/images/hosting/11/aspnet_tutorial11_CustomErrors_cs_figure01.png?cdn_id=2014-12-04-001

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66513/discussion-between-omer-and-harry-boy).